# How to connect to a specific pod from a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a set of pods in a deployment, and I'd like to have a pod in the same namespace be able to connect to one of the *specific* pods in the deployment. For instance, I'd like the ability to connect directly to an exposed port on pod `my-pod-55785865c5-cjxfs`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post your deployment yaml for the pod(s) in question? I'm guessing a service like @Harsh Manvar suggested but it depend on the deployment

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pod IP to connect to it. However the pod IPs are ephemeral. As soon as the pod dies and comes back up, the IP changes. Keep that in mind.

Pod to pod communication: `pod-ip.namespace.pod` but still the IPs are ephemeral.

Comment: while the main part about ephemeral nature of pods is correct, the part about lack of ability to reach pods by their names is incorrect: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

Answer (score 1):

You can create the service and use it as the method to create connection. Kubernetes services : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Pod to Pod communication: `pod-ip.namespace.pod`

Service to service communication : `service-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`

However you can also use pod IP clusterIP to make connections but with a pod restart the IP changes.

Comment: I've tried the internal pod to pod communication but as far as I can tell this doesn't appear to work for a Deployment. I do notice this does work for a StatefulSet, where the fqdn is `statefulset-pod-name.service-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`, but I'm hoping to not use a StatefulSet if possible.

Comment: @chris.mclennon yes it will be better to use deployment only rather statefulset unless and until having application requirements.